# how to avoid 'Database is Locked' Error in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I've searched all over but I can't find any solution for me.
I have sequences in my program where I do 'select' commands then follow it with 'update' or 'insert' commands. I'm suspecting this is where I got this error. Please help me how I can avoid this. I can't use try catch because the error appears few seconds after I trigger the event.

Comment: You should reuse the same connection for your operations.